# How to Read a Multi CSV in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a log file that looks like the following:

```
A, colA1, colA2
B, colB1,
C, colC1, colC2, colC3, colC4
A, 1, 3
B, 2
C, 3, 1, 2, 4
...
```

Essentially, the log file contains *multiple* CSV files. Each row starts with an identifier for the csv file, then dumps a row.

Currently, I use `grep A,` on the log to return the following output:

```
A, colA1, colA2
A, 1, 3
...
```

Which I can then read using pandas into a dataframe. However, I have to do this for B, and C. 
I am wondering if there is a way to load this log file in one go without the intermediate step of greping and storing to a local csv file?

Comment: @shaikmoeed No, this question is different. I am asking about loading a multi csv file, not loading multiple csv files into one dataframe and concatenating it.

Comment: How big is the file? I would just read the file line by line and process manually.

Comment: @QuangHoang Around 5 Gb

Comment: That's essentially 5GB in RAM. Just do a `for` loop. It may take about couple of minutes.

Answer (score -1):

Pandas indexing can help here. Just read the file in one object and then apply the conditions to segregate the data in three objects based the indicator column.

check below example:

```
import pandas as pd
complete_obj = pd.read_csv(file_loc)

file_A_obj = complete_obj[complete_obj['indicator_col']=='A']
file_B_obj = complete_obj[complete_obj['indicator_col']=='B']
file_C_obj = complete_obj[complete_obj['indicator_col']=='C']
```